# Can you pass props to a layout in sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit

I am working on a site with SvelteKit and I want to have a layout with a navbar for each page. The navbar has links with the active link being the page you are on. Is there a way I can pass a prop from each page to the template that changes which link is active?

Thanks!

Comment: This hasn't been answered for a long time. There's no way I know to pass props to the layout. There may be – but it's better to use the global states, or sveltekit's event.url.pathname api to coditionally make it active.

Comment: Do you mind accepting the answer if it was useful?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I kind of forgot about this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I know what you're looking for. SvelteKit comes with the default `page` store. `$page.url.pathname` subscribes to that store and returns the current pathname. There are several ways you could apply this.

The following example creates a component `Navlink.svelte`, which

1. Imports the default Svelte store `page`
2. Creates a reactive boolean `active` and sets it to true when `$page.url.pathname` equals `href`. The `$:` make it reactive, meaning that Svelte reruns the code whenever either `$page.url.pathname` or `href` changes.
3. In the `a` element, we pass `href` as a prop. Whenever you use the Navlink component, you pass it `href` like you would a regular `a` element. That is also why we use `export let href`.
4. We also add `class:active`. This is the Svelte way of applying classes conditionally. Note that this is actually shorthand for `class:active={active}`, meaning we apply the class `active` when the variable `active` (after the equal sign) is true. When the variable and the class share the same name, we can use `class:active`. ([docs on this subject](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name))
5. Style the `.active` class however you like.

```html
<script>
  import { page } from "$app/stores"
  export let href
  $: active = $page.url.pathname === href
</script>

<a {href} class:active>
  <slot />
</a>

<style>
  a.active {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

You can also use a Tailwind class combined with some inline logic:

```html
<a class:text-primary={$page.url.pathname === '/about'} href="/about">About</a>
```

Or use traditional CSS combined with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```html
<a href="/about" class="{($page.url.pathname === '/about')? active : inactive}"
```